# Detect app restart under node-dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dev

I am developing Node.js application using Node-dev. Each time I save the script of the application (press Control-S) node-dev will restart my app. Now the question, can I detect the restart withing the application, so that I can save some data before the program is terminated?

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
   console.log('SIGINT');
});
```

The code above does not detect this kind of restart.

I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your child, add a listener on the `exit` event of `process`:

```
process.on('exit', function() {
  // Save application state
});
```

---

As you can see from the source, `node-dev` forks to launch your script. When one file changes, the parent [launches its `stop()` function](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev/blob/master/lib/index.js#L21-L34), waits for the child to exit and then restarts it:

```
child.on('exit', start)
stop()
```

The [`stop()` function](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev/blob/master/lib/index.js#L61-L64) sends a message:

```
ipc.send({exit: true}, child)
```

The [ipc object](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev/blob/master/lib/ipc.js#L11-L15) uses the [`child.send()` method](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle):

```
if (dest.send) dest.send(m)
```

`node-dev` doesn't work by sending a `SIGINT` signal, but works using IPCs. It would seem that you can then detect the restart of your application by adding a listener on the [`message` event of `process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message)... but this doesn't work (ie. the `message` event is never emitted on the `process` object). My guess is that `process.exit()` is synchronous and that our handler doesn't get the chance to run.

*Edit:* [here](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/7542247) is a Gist with an example of parent/child communication using IPC in Node, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. But it does not work for me. Probably because I am using Windows XP.

Comment: What isn't working? Do you catch an event? If you do a `console.log(m)` inside the `process.on('message')`, does it output anything?

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying to do. no output. I thought that maybe the console handle is invalid and tried to save to file instead, nothing. the process.on('message') does not fire.